ffmpeg - rtp file as input
does ffmpeg support file in rtp format as input ? I have tried raw rtp data or rtpdump format, but it does not work. I guess the trouble is how rtp is read from file.File is not fragmented to individual packets,so i guess ffmpeg have no clue how long is packet and where starts next rtp header. So is there any chance to use rtp/rtpdump file directly in ffmpeg and convert it to audio ?
for example:
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -f rtp -i ./output.rtp test.wav
[rtp @ 000001812de47bc0] Unsupported RTP version packet received
Last message repeated 10 times
[rtp @ 000001812de47bc0] Unable to receive RTP payload type 71 without an SDP file describing it
[in#0 @ 000001812de477c0] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening input file ./output.rtp.
rtp file is valid file with RTP payload type 08.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
